# A Script Engine that Interprets Java

Tags: java, scripting, scripting-language, jvm-languages

I remember running into an open source project that built a Java scripting engine that interprets Java (no, not Rhino, that's for JavaScript, it runs Java).  If you have come across that project, please share Link(s).

(Of course doing a Google search of the word combination of Java and scripting returns all the JavaScript results, alas, that is not what I am looking for damn you google!!!)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/). From their site:

> BeanShell is a small, free, embeddable **Java source interpreter** with object scripting language features, written in Java. BeanShell dynamically executes **standard Java syntax** and extends it with common scripting conveniences such as loose types, commands, and method closures like those in Perl and JavaScript.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: I found what I was looking for:  it's called janino. Located at http://janino.codehaus.org. It's an embedable Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org) or [Grails](http://grails.org)?  Which are scripting languages that convert into bytecode.

Comment: I found what I was looking for:  it's called janino. Located at http://janino.codehaus.org. It's an embedable Java compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Jikes research VM is Java written in Java.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jikes_RVM

And here's a list of Java implementations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines